# Stop Windows Defender from scanning a drive right now

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm working on cleaning some old data off of some hard drives, and I have a USB SATA adapter for accessing the drives. The adapter correctly registers itself as a removable media controller, so windows provides me with the option to "safely eject the drive," but I'm always hit with the "This device is currently in use" error message. Looking in the events viewer, it appears that the process accessing the drive is a scanning program from Windows Defender:

```
The application \Device\HarddiskVolume8\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.2008.9-0\MsMpEng.exe with process id 33960 stopped the removal or ejection for the device USB...
```

I've tried disabling realtime protection in windows defender, stopping windows defender all together, and adding an exclusion for the drive. None of these actions did kill the scan, and I've had to resort to rebooting to avoid ripping out the drive while it is being accessed. Is there a way to kill an active defender scan while it's in progress? I do want windows defender to keep running on this computer for anti-malware purposes, I just want to be able to kill these specific scans on demand.

Answer (score 0):

Windows *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media* does not always work, whether for the legitimate reason that the drive is in use, or simply because it occasionally fails to respond for unknown reason. Third-party tools, such as [HotSwap](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm) or many [alternative applications](https://alternativeto.net/software/hotswap/), are, in my experience, more reliable. Use them with caution, because some *might* interrupt a write operation, though *HotSwap* does offer a spindown option to allow HDD usage to finish.

As with any third-party software, check before installation for malware, such as by using [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure all instances of Windows Explorer are closed. Open Explorer Windows cause Safely Eject to fail. This has happened to me numerous times and closing open Explorer Windows usually solves the problem.

Only rarely is Windows Defender actively scanning on eject. I do not recall this happening to me.

Answer (score -3):

Defender is pretty useless, I would disable it and delete it. I have yet to find it detect any valid threat with many downloaded and installed by intent to test it.

Your protected low impact protection is a good browser like Firefox as the best defence behind NAT and a firewall.

You are far better to run Malwarebytes adwcleaner.exe and use an alert program for autoruns of potential trojans scheduled in the registry.

Although I forbid myself to run W10 again and the question was never asked how to remove Windows Defender, this may be followed...

To disable the Windows 10 antivirus temporarily, use these steps:
Open Start.
Search for Windows Security and click the top result to open the app.
Click on Virus & threat protection.
Under the "Virus & threat protection settings" section,
click the Manage settings option.

Turn off the Real-time protection toggle switch to disable Microsoft Although this isn't a permanent solution, it's the best option to disable the Windows 10 antivirus to perform a specific task

Then enter Group Policy

```
    Search for gpedit.msc and click the top result to open the Local Group Policy Editor.
    Browse the following path:
```

Computer Configuration > Administrative     Templates > Windows Components >
Microsoft Defender Antivirus.

Double-click the Turn off Microsoft Defender Antivirus policy.

If you want to disable the Microsoft Defender Antivirus feature, you now have two choices. You can temporarily disable the real-time protection, or you may still be able to permanently disable it using the Group Policy Editor on Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise with the instructions outlined above.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\DisableAntiSpyware. =1

Then under scheduled tasks delete all the useless maintenance scans and call home reports including Defender updates.